# timer to calculate seconds not being implemented properly

Tags: c++

I am making a timer to calculate the number of seconds until the user presses 3 however the program doesn't work, and no value is saved in the integer variable 'sec'.
where am i wrong?
I have include windows.h and ctime.h
Here's the code:

```
       void func(){
       int sec=0
       cout<<"Press 3 to end Timer";
                cin>>t;
                
                while(t!=3){
                Sleep(1);
                sec++;}
                
                if(t==3)
                {
                    cout<<"Timer ended";
                }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

This is because cin >> t is blocking. That is, execution doesn't move to your while-loop until the input is complete.

Something like this would work:

```
#include <chrono>

// This is just to make the example cleaner.
using namespace chrono;

...

system_clock::time_point startTime = system_clock::now();

cin >> t;

system_clock::time_point endTime = system_clock::now();
milliseconds duration = time_point_cast<milliseconds>(endTime - startTime);
```

At this point, duration.count() is the number of milliseconds spent waiting for input. You can do some math to turn it into seconds, or you could use seconds instead like this:

```
seconds duration = time_point_cast<seconds>(endTime - startTime);
```

but in this case, 2.9 seconds will show up as 2 seconds (I think). So I'd do this to output it:

```
cout << "Duration: " << (double)duration.count() / 1000.0 << endl;
```

Or something along those lines. I'm typing this raw, so there might be typos.

Comment: do i move that after the if statement?

Comment: What you can do is get the time before the cin, get the time after the cin, and then calculate. I'll update my answer a little.